# How to Filter the Html Table list in asp.net mvc by using jquery in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi i'm trying to filter the html table list in asp.net mvc by using jquery on the change of dropdown ,DropDown Contain the Product Name and i want to filter the table row  which contain 
changed Product Name ,any Body Please help me out,,I am tried  and search here  but i can't get the correct solution

my Table List is

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supplier.CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuantityPerUnit)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityPerUnit)
            </td>
         </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and my dropdown list code is

```
<div id="dropdownlist">
    @Html.DropDownList("ProductName", string.Empty);
</div>
```

Dropdown contain Productname

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should add a class or id to your table and/or a class on your table rows.

```
$("#dropdownlist").on("change", function (e) {
    var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    var tableSelector = "table"; // <-change this if you put a class or id on your table
    var $table = $(tableSelector);
    $table.find("tr").hide().filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).find("td:first").text()) == selected; }).show();
});
```

Comment: hi Rodney ,its not working ,it return empty result after matching the product name

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I fixed the `.filter()` method to look only at the first table cell, and to trim whitespace off the contents.

Comment: thanx ,its working but is there any another way ,so that without using (td:first) ,searched the row and then filter

Answer (score -1):

```
    function Record(C1, C2, C3, C4, I1, I2) {
        this.C1 = C1;
        this.C2 = C2;
        this.C3 = C3;
        this.C4 = C4;
        this.I1 = I1;
        this.I2 = I2;

    }

        var r1 = new RECORD("2014-01-01", "Maroc", "Rabat", "Diesel", "100", "10000")
        var r2 = new RECORD("2014-05-01", "Maroc", "Rabat", "Diesel", "100", "10000")
        var r3 = new RECORD("2014-08-01", "Maroc", "Rabat", "Essence", "50", "2500")
        var r4 = new RECORD("2014-02-01", "Maroc", "Casablanca", "Essence", "50", "2500")
        var r5 = new RECORD("2014-07-01", "Maroc", "Casablanca", "Diesel", "90", "9000")
        var r6 = new RECORD("2014-10-01", "Maroc", "Casablanca", "Essence", "50", "2500")
        var r7 = new RECORD("2014-04-01", "Maroc", "Marrakech", "Essence", "50", "2500")
        var r8 = new RECORD("2014-06-01", "Maroc", "Marrakech", "Essence", "50", "2500")
        var r9 = new RECORD("2014-09-01", "Maroc", "Marrakech", "Diesel", "70", "7000")
        var r10 = new RECORD("2014-03-01", "Maroc", "Casablanca", "Diesel", "80", "8000")


        var report = new Array;

        rapport[0] = r1;
        rapport[1] = r2;
        rapport[2] = r3;
        rapport[3] = r4;
        rapport[4] = r5;
        rapport[5] = r6;
        rapport[6] = r7;
        rapport[7] = r8;
        rapport[8] = r9;
        rapport[9] = r10;


    function FilterReport(C1, C2, I1) {

        var FilterReport = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
            rapport[i].C1
            rapport[i].C2
            rapport[i].I1

        }
        var FilterReport = new FilterReport(C1, C2, I1);

        FilterReport[i] = r1;
        FilterReport[i] = r2;
        FilterReport[i] = r3;
        FilterReport[i] = r4;
        FilterReport[i] = r5;
        FilterReport[i] = r6;
        FilterReport[i] = r7;
        FilterReport[i] = r8;
        FilterReport[i] = r9;
        FilterReport[i] = r10

        alert("C1:" + C1 + "C2:" + C2 + "I1:" + I1);


    }
```